# React how to create Notifications without npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications

Hi i just started learning react.
Is it possible to do this without classes (functional programming)?
Index.js has a button with an axios call.
When the answer came, a notification should appear and disappear in a second.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Index from './components/index/index';

import Notifications from './components/notifications/notifications';

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
             <Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Index notification={ <Notifications/> } /> } />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const axios = require('axios');

const Index = (props) => {

    let getData = () => {
        axios.get('url')
        .then(function (response) {
            <Notification text={ response.data }/> );
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }); 
    }

    return (
            <button onClick={ () => getData() }>Get data</button>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

**Notification.js**

```
import React  from 'react';

const Notification = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>props.text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    //and delete after 1 second
}

export default  Notification;
```

Please show examples of functional solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use redux for achieve this, when you receive data from API, dispatch a redux action who return a true/false boolean.

The benefit of this proposal solution, after you developing system, you need to call only one function, and dispatch this into your store that's it !!

Place you `<Notification />` component at top of your app

Like :

```
const App = (props) => {
    return (
       <Provider store={store}>
         <Notification />
         <BrowserRouter>
             <Route exact path="/" render={/* YOUR HOMEPAGE COMPONENT */} />
        </BrowserRouter>
       </Provider>
    );
}
```

Please look redux solution here : https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Inside your `<Notification />`

Don't forget to connect at redux you should use the `connect()` is an HOC (High Order Component)

```js
import React  from 'react';
import { connect }  from 'redux'

const Notification = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>props.text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    //and delete after 1 second
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  /* Get your state from your store notification for example */
  return {}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `axios.then`, you can store the result in state, and set a timeout to clear the state 1s later. Then you render Notification if there is something in state

```
const Index = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState();

    let getData = () => {
        axios.get('url')
            .then(function (response) {
                setText(response.data);
                setTimeout(() => setText(), 1000);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => getData()}>Get data</button>
            {text &&
                <Notification text={text} />
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's better if it use redux, you should just call an action

Comment: He's not using redux

Comment: Yes, but I recommend to use this ! He is a better solution for application (When it's not an abuse)

Answer (score 0):

To render a notification in the screen, normally I would use React [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

In order to do that your Notification component need to render to DOM through Portal

```
const notificationRoot = document.getElementById('notification-root'); // Create the element in your main html file in order for your notification to "portal" in

const Notification = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>props.text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const DisplayNotification = () => {
  const domNode = usememo(() => document.createElement('div'), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    notificationRoot.appendChild(domNode);
    return () => {
      notificationRoot.removeChild(domNode);
    }
  }, [])

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <Notification />,
    domNode
  ); // Portal to your node
}
```

By rendering `DisplayNotification`, your `Notification` should pop up.